# jQuery event triggering vs Native. Can't explain differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-chosen

I've run into an issue while integrating a couple of jQuery plugins.

I'm using a third party plugin on an eCommerce website to provide a 'postcode lookup' function. This library has been provided with minified source so is proving hard to debug, but binds onto an existing form on our site, with a pop-up appearing when various fields are interacted with (in order to search for an address base on the post/zip code)

```
<select id="countries"><!-- options--></select>
```

This works fine with a regular form (events are triggered on the native 'select' element, which in turn launches the plugin, in this case after a country is selected from this dropdown)

I have then added the 'chosen.js' plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in order to provide some additional functionality to the select field (make it searchable). This plugin binds to the *same* element as the third party plugin, hiding the 'real' select element and constructed a 'fake' select menu using styled markup and css. When this 'fake' form element is interacted with, it triggers events on the 'real' form select element when the widget is interacted with.

**edit**
From the unobfuscated source I've pinpointed where this change is initially caught... This doesn't mean much to me in this form...

```
function u(n) {
    function u() {
        e.focus(n)
    }
    (i.append(e.element), n && n.tagName) && (i.inputField(n) && (t(n, "keyup", e.keyup), t(n, "keydown", e.keydown), t(n, "focus", u), t(n, "blur", e.blur), t(n, "keypress", e.keypress), n == r.activeElement && u()), t(n, "click", function() {
        e.click(n)
    }), t(n, "dblclick", function() {
        e.dblclick(n)
    }), t(n, "change", function() {
        e.change(n)
    }))
}
```

I can bind my own debug event to this function and I can see the event being fired on the underlying element.

```
$('select').on('change', function(){ console.log('changed!'); });
```

However - what I've found that the chosen.js plugin is breaking the postcode lookup plugin. It doesn't appear to be firing the event in the same way as the select element alone.

I've dug into the source (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.js) and found the following function:

```
Chosen.prototype.result_select = function(evt) {
      // .... snip
      // where 'this.form_field_jq' is a jQuery wrapped 'select'
      this.form_field_jq.trigger("change", {
        'selected': this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value
      });
  }
};
```

As can be seen - the underlying element is having change event triggered on it, and I can see the result of that with my debug event listener. However this event it not being picked up by the postcode lookup library. **However** If I add a 'native' event to the same function iwhtin chosen.js (not using jQuery) - the plugin is triggered.

```
Chosen.prototype.result_select = function(evt) {
      // .... snip
      // where 'this.form_field_jq' is a jQuery wrapped 'select'
      this.form_field_jq.trigger("change", {
        'selected': this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value
      });
      // everything works together if I add these two lines
      var myEvent = new CustomEvent('change');
      this.form_field_jq.get(0).dispatchEvent(myEvent);
      // the other plugin is triggered after dispatching this event.
  }
};
```

What could be happening here?

Comment: jQuery `trigger()` method fires the handlers you bound to an event, but it doesn't actually trigger the default behavior. For example, using `trigger("click",...)` on a link won't make the browser follow the link. It will only trigger the event handlers you set.
On the contrary, native JavaScript *will also* trigger the default behavior. So `$("a")[0].click()` would trigger the event handlers *and* make the browser follow the link.

Does that help you ?

Comment: Well - could the postcode library have bound to the 'change' event in a way that would not be triggered by using the jQuery trigger? As you can see - all I'm doing is firing a CustomEvent with the name 'change' against the element, and this produces the correct behaviour. What puzzles me is exactly what is different?

Comment: Hmmm... it's really hard to tell without your "postcode library" code. You should try to find the snippet where the event is bound, de-minificate it and show it to us.

Without that code, it could a lot of different things
For the moment, I've thought of 2 possible reasons : 
- I've looked into the chosen.js source code. The snipped you included in your post is actually wrapped in a conditional statement : `if (this.is_multiple || this.form_field.selectedIndex !== this.current_selectedIndex) {`. When you tried firing a native JS event, did you put your code *inside* the conditional statement ?

Comment: If not, that could be the reason.

Otherwise, I see that extra parameters are passed along to the handler ( `'selected': this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value`). I think it's passed for a reason. I guess the value of `selected` is checked when the event is fired. Perhaps, it's (badly) cached and thus, not working when the chosen.js plugin triggers a value it has already cached. If no value is provided (like when you're triggering the handler with native JS), maybe it assumes the value of your `select` has changed.

But it's *really* hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: The code is here: https://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/js/captureplus-2.10.min.js?key=nk41-cn21-ba52-th64

Comment: I'll extract the relevant function and add it to the original post

Comment: Also @WaldoJeffers in response to your questions: 1) Yes I placed my code inside the conditional statement - and this _does_ work. What I'm asking is _why_ I need to do this, when there is already a change event being dispatched on the original element (via $.trigger('change')

Comment: Well I just suggested you some reasons why it *might* not work without your code. I'm probably wrong, but still, you should try to see if that `selected` parameter has anything influence.